# Frozen snapshot of list rendered with SwipeRefreshLayout in ViewPager

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-viewpager, swiperefreshlayout

Consider an Android activity that is subclass of`android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity`. It contains several apges managed by `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`. Each page contains a `ListView` wrapped by `android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout`. The following screenshot shows the initial state of this activity.

[image: initial activity state]

Now, I swipe down to refresh the list on page 0. The refresh animation appears. Now, let's swipe to the right on page 2 and then back to page 0.

The refresh animation is still visible. This seems strange to me as page 0 was destroyed and created again. Moreover, if I swipe up (trying to scroll to the end of the list on page 0) some strange layer is rendered over the page which seems to contain the old state of the page from the time it was destroyed.

[image: swipe refresh issue]

I have no idea why this happens and how to fix it. Thanks for any help.

Here is the source code of a minimal application that consists of 3 layout files, an activity class, a fragment class, a manifest file and a build script.

swipeandroid/src/main/res/layout/service_schedule_activity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/servicePager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v4.view.PagerTabStrip
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top"/>

</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

swipeandroid/src/main/res/layout/service_schedule_tab_fragment.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/serviceRefreshLayout"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/timeSlots"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

swipeandroid/src/main/res/layout/service_schedule_row.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/time"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

swipeandroid/src/main/java/com/swipetest/ServiceScheduleActivity.java

```
package com.swipetest;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;

public class ServiceScheduleActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(final Bundle inState) {
        // call super class
        super.onCreate(inState);

        // set content
        setContentView(R.layout.service_schedule_activity);

        // set up service pager
        ((ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.servicePager)).setAdapter(new ServiceFragmentPagerAdapter());
    }

    private class ServiceFragmentPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
        public ServiceFragmentPagerAdapter() {
            super(getSupportFragmentManager());
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 5;
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(final int position) {
            return ServiceScheduleTabFragment.newInstance(position);
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(final int position) {
            return String.format("page %d", position);
        }
    }
}
```

swipeandroid/src/main/java/com/swipetest/ServiceScheduleTabFragment.java

```
package com.swipetest;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ServiceScheduleTabFragment extends Fragment {
    private static final String TAB_POSITION_ARGUMENT = "tabPosition";

    public static ServiceScheduleTabFragment newInstance(final int tabPosition) {
        // prepare arguments
        final Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
        arguments.putInt(TAB_POSITION_ARGUMENT, tabPosition);

        // create fragment
        final ServiceScheduleTabFragment fragment = new ServiceScheduleTabFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(arguments);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater layoutInflater, final ViewGroup parent, final Bundle inState) {
        // create fragment root view
        final View rootView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.service_schedule_tab_fragment, parent, false);

        // initialize time slot list view
        final ListView timeSlotListView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.timeSlots);
        timeSlotListView.setAdapter(new TimeSlotListAdapter());

        // return fragment root view
        return rootView;
    }

    private int getTabPosition() {
        return getArguments().getInt(TAB_POSITION_ARGUMENT);
    }

    private static class TimeSlotRowViewHolder {
        private final TextView timeView;

        public TimeSlotRowViewHolder(final View rowView) {
            timeView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.time);
        }

        public TextView getTimeView() {
            return timeView;
        }
    }

    private class TimeSlotListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 80;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(final int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(final int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, final View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
            // reuse or create row view
            final View rowView;
            if (convertView != null) {
                rowView = convertView;
            } else {
                rowView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.service_schedule_row, parent, false);
                rowView.setTag(new TimeSlotRowViewHolder(rowView));
            }

            // fill data
            final TimeSlotRowViewHolder rowViewHolder = (TimeSlotRowViewHolder) rowView.getTag();
            rowViewHolder.getTimeView().setText(String.format("tab %d, row %d", getTabPosition(), position));
            return rowView;
        }
    }
}
```

swipeandroid/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.swipetest"
          android:versionCode="1"
          android:versionName="1.0">

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16" android:targetSdkVersion="23"/>

    <application
        android:name="android.app.Application"
        android:label="Swipe Test"
        android:allowBackup="false">

        <activity
            android:name="com.swipetest.ServiceScheduleActivity">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

swipeandroid/build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile "com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1"
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            debuggable true
            minifyEnabled false
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: where do you initialize the SwipeToRefresh Layout

Comment: @Veeresh Charantimath In this minimal app, no listener is added to SwipeRefreshLayout. In my real and much larger app, there is of course such listener but the bug occurs anyway.

Comment: you can set 'swiperefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false)' when you need to stop the swipe refresh.

Comment: @Ragu Swaminathan Call to `swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false)` is fine if the real refreshing action (say a HTTP request to a server) is completed before the user swipes to next page (say from page 0 to page 1). However, I should not call `swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false)` if the action is still in progress. If the user swipes to page 1 before the action is completed, then a subsequent call to `swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false)` will not prevent the bug.

Comment: do you fix the isssue .. ?

Comment: try to clear the list and then load the new data on swipe refresh

Comment: @Ragu Swaminathan What do you mean by "on swipe refresh"? In `SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener#onRefresh()`? (i.e. when the refresh animation starts and before the new data are available)

Comment: @Ragu Swaminathan Clearing the list immediately after swipe gesture works (+1) and it is an acceptable solution. From the user point of view, I would prefer if the old data remain on the screen until the new data are available. (Just like in a web browser. If you press Ctrl + R, you are not looking at a blank page while fresh data are loaded.)

Comment: Shall i post this as an answer ?

Comment: @Ragu Swaminathan Of course, you can. :) I am making some more investigation. I am trying to modify the behavior of `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`. I am trying to make it forget the state of a page once the page is destroyed and create the page again from scratch if the user returns to it.

Comment: Forgetting the page state in modified `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` is possible (observed that position in `ListView` is not restored anymore) but it does not solve the bug anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I have discovered a workaround that is very simple to implement and fixes the issue.

Just wrap the `SwipeRefreshLayout` e.g. by `FrameLayout`. It seems that the `ViewPager` does not like `SwipeRefreshLayout` being the root of the view hierarchy of a page fragment.

Anyway, this issue looks like a bug in Android Support Library. See
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=194957

I have also tried other workarounds that do not work:

- Replacing `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` by `FragmentPagerAdapter will not help.
- Calling `mySwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false)` in `onPause` will not help.
- Modifying the `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` so that it does not remeber states of destroyed pages will not help.

The following workarounds can help somehow but I prefer the suggested wrapping of `SwipeRefreshLayout` anyway:

- Clearing the data (so that the `ListView` contains no rows) in `SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener#onRefresh()` helps only if the `ListView` has transparent background. The unwanted snapshot is probably still rendered over the first page but it is fully transparent.
- You can disallow paging for the time of refresh animation. However, this takes some effort as you must subclass both `ViewPager` and `PagerTabStrip` and prevent appropriate UI events in your subclasses.
- Of course, you can avoid using `SwipeRefreshLayout` in `ViewPager` completely but this does not seem to be necessary.

Comment: @CimIman please answer this too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36434071/android-support-v4-widget-swiperefreshlayout-working-but-it-is-not-visible

Comment: @Hammad Nasir Sorry but that seems to be a completely different issue and i have no idea about it.

Answer (score 2):

> Try to clear the list and then load the new data on swipe refresh.

As mentioned in the comment.

Comment: Btw. it seems to be a bug in Android Support Library: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=194957

Comment: Well, this workaround works only if the `ListView` is transparent. The `SwipeRefreshLayout` takes some snapshot before it is destroyed and this snapshot is rendered over the page when it is re-created. It does not do any harm only if the snapshot does not contain any single non-transparent pixel.

Comment: Sorry for changing the accepted answer to my own one. However, I came with another workaround that seems much better to me.