# Viewpager with SwipeRefreshLayout when refresh the icon doesn't go away

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-viewpager, swiperefreshlayout

My question is exactly like this one.

[Frozen snapshot of list rendered with SwipeRefreshLayout in ViewPager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36087295/frozen-snapshot-of-list-rendered-with-swiperefreshlayout-in-viewpager)

But in short, I refresh the list and the spinning thing still keeps going after the list has been refreshed.

I tried the following solution he gave of wrapping the SwipeRefreshLayout with a FrameLayout and i had no success.

Here are screenshots of what I have right now, and the code where I implement this.

[image]
[image]

In my Fragment Class and parts of my Asynctask,

```
private LocationUtil loc;
private static final String ARG_SORT_TYPE = "sortType";
String sortType = null;
private ArrayList<Facility> results;
private SwipeRefreshLayout mPtrListView;
private ListView waitTimesListView;
SummaryAdapter adapter;

 @Override
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_wait_times_viewpager_fragment,container,false);

    mPtrListView = (SwipeRefreshLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.wait_times_pull_refresh_list);
    waitTimesListView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.wait_times_listview);
    waitTimesListView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    mPtrListView.setOnRefreshListener(this);

    WaitTimesTask task = new WaitTimesTask(getActivity());
    task.execute(sortType, longitudeLocation, latitudeLocation);
    return view;
}

 @Override
 public void onRefresh() {
    WaitTimesTask task = new WaitTimesTask(getActivity());
    task.execute("name", longitudeLocation, latitudeLocation);
}

public void setLocation(){
    if(loc.useSmartLocation()){
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

        if (location != null) {
            Log.v("Check Location frag" + sortType + " " , " " + location.getLongitude() + " "  + location.getLatitude());

            latitudeLocation = Double.toString(location.getLatitude());
            longitudeLocation = Double.toString(location.getLongitude());

        } else {
            Log.v("Check waitTimesActivity" , " is null");
            }
    }
    else {
        loc.determineLocation();
        latitudeLocation = Double.toString(loc.getLatitude());
        longitudeLocation = Double.toString(loc.getLongitude());
    }
}

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        dialog = AsyncProgressDialog.show(mContext, "", "");
        setLocation();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String string) {
        if (dialog != null && dialog.isShowing()) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
        if(string != null){
            Log.v("result on post & type: " + Sort, string);

            NovantFacilityXmlParser parser = new NovantFacilityXmlParser();
            string = string.replace("&", "&amp;");
            try {
                results = parser.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(string.getBytes()));

            } catch (IOException | XmlPullParserException ex) {
                Log.e("Parsing error:", ex.getMessage());
            }

            Log.v("SetUp "," of List");

            if(!results.isEmpty()) {
                adapter = new SummaryAdapter(mContext, R.layout.row_wait_time, results.toArray(new Facility[results.size()]));
                waitTimesListView.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "No data available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
}
```

My xml, both fragment and main activity.

Activity xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@color/aubergine">

<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/wait_times_tab_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:tabIndicatorHeight="3dp"
    app:tabIndicatorColor="#ffffff"
    app:tabSelectedTextColor="#ffffff"
    app:tabMode="fixed"
    android:background="#333333"/>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/wait_times_ViewPager">
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
</LinearLayout>
```

Fragment xml

```
<FrameLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/base_color">
<!--tools:context=".WaitTimesFragment">-->

        <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
            android:id="@+id/wait_times_pull_refresh_list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            >

            <ListView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/wait_times_listview"/>

        </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
    <include layout="@layout/novant_menu_layout" />
```

In my OnpostExecute, I get the string from the doinBackground and parse the xml feed and make an arraylist that i use for my adapter that i custom made.

Any help would greatly be appreciated. 
Thanks.

Comment: i am facing the same issue . would you please you suggest any solution ?

Comment: The solution below worked for me. On the post do the following, mPtrListView.setRefreshing(false). But as you can see, I'm also using a ProgressDialog in the AsyncTask. I used a boolean that i set to true in the onRefresh. I then used this boolean to determine if i should show the ProgressDialog again whenever the user refreshes, in which i wont show if they are refreshing. @AdeelTurk

Answer (score 2):

Please, add `mPtrListView.setRefreshing(false)` in `onPostExecute`.

Comment: You the man! I think that this should be ok for my case. I kind of threw this out the window since the other post mentioned that it wasn't an ideal solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think its bit late but It may help someone in future

You must call setRefreshing(false) in your overridden **onRefresh()** method

```
@Override
 public void onRefresh() {
    WaitTimesTask task = new WaitTimesTask(getActivity());
    task.execute("name", longitudeLocation, latitudeLocation);
    mPtrListView.setRefreshing(false); //this method call will resolve your problem 
}
```